# Unable to Unzip Downloaded ZIP file

Tags: download, installation, debian, wget, unzip

Im trying to download a zip file to a VPS (Debian 7) but Im having some problems. To download the file I used

```
wget http://www.mediafire.com/download/db8bim3hba21cc7/RobinBot.zip
```

and got this
http://pastebin.com/aBheGBgT

I then use

```
unzip RobinBot.zip
```

and

```
unzip RobinBot
```

I get a response of this http://pastebin.com/Sfpm39Kh

Any suggestions?
(I apologize for the very bad format of this)

Thank you

Buck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded a HTML intermediate page, not the zip file.